# how to disable auto-create exe file when compile c / c++ in VS Code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, mingw, exe

I have used VS Code

But VS Code create .exe file when compile c or c++ file.

I never have seen such like this when I used Atom.

What I want is VS Code does't create .exe file.

what should I do?

++attach pic

Before

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q2pn.jpg)

After

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSuhg.jpg)

I just compile simple ccc.cpp file which print "eee".

After compile, there is a executable.

Comment: You do know that the goal of the compiling process is to get an executable right?

Comment: @Vivick: Not necessarily.

Comment: Could you say what you want the compile process to produce?

Comment: If the desired output is not an executable, I'd have to assume it is an object file for the linker. But that shouldn't be an assumption. The question should state what is wanted.

Comment: If you don't want the compiler to create an executable you need to adjust the compilation command accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can't get output from a program that doesn't exist.

Modern compilers don't compile a program and run it directly from memory.  You need to write it to disk first, then you can run it.

The last compiler I'm aware of that did that was Turbo Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

so my guess is you don't want the .exe file to show ... you either want vscode to create the .exe file in some other dump folder or you want it to delete after running the program

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, please use the comments section for that